# How to add check constraint CHECK constraint to the APP_DATE column to make sure that all appointments are before 02/01/2012

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

ALTER TABLE OFFICE

ADD CONSTRAINT check_APP_DATE CHECK (APP_DATE < ’02-01-2012’);

I have tried to use the above commands but I am getting error. 
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00911: invalid character

is it the correct way to check CONSTRAINT in sqlplus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the TO_DATE function:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT check_APP_DATE CHECK (APP_DATE < TO_DATE(’02-01-2012’,'DD-MM-YYYY'));
```